# Convert DataRow type to Version and itterate through list of versions

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script, where part of its job is to grab a list of versions from a table in my SQL database and compare them to a version in a file. If *any one* of the version numbers in the DB is higher than that of the file, the script should error and not continue, even if some of the versions in the database pass (basically the highest version should be what determines if the script fails). For reference, the SQL Cmd exports something like this:

```
Column1
-------
2019.3.3
2020.3
4.21.0.3
4.24.0.1
4.26.0.2
4.27.2
4.27.3
4.27.7
4.33.10
```

The script is as follows.

```
. .\Get-AppVersion.ps1

# Get latest version in the server_long_entry table
$databaseVersion = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $DBInstance -Database $DBName -Query "SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING([version], 0, CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%.[^0-9.]%', [version]) <> 0 THEN PATINDEX('%.[^0-9.]%', [version]) ELSE 100 END) FROM dbo.server_log_entry"

$databaseVersion = $databaseVersion | Select-Object Column1

#Calls custom function to get version of the file as System.Version type
$version = Get-AppVersion $Source 

# Checks to make sure the the version in the DB is lower than that of the App version.
foreach($versionofdb in $databaseVersion) {
    if ($version -lt [version]$versionofdb) { 
        Write-Error "Database Version is a higher version than Instance Version. Unable to continue"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Versions compatible"
    }
}
```

When I run this, it states

> Cannot convert value "@{Column1=2019.3.3}" to type "System.Version". Error: "Cannot convert the "@{Column1=2019.3.3}" value of type "Selected.System.Data.DataRow" to type "System.Version"."

I know this is because its trying to convert the DataRow type to System.Version, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix this. If the SQL Query was only returning one value, I believe I could use

```
$databaseVersion = $databaseVersion.ItemArray[0].ToString()
```

But in this case the list is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As currently written, the `$versionofdb` is of `[PSCustomObject]` type. You need to cast a *string* to the `[version]` type. Use  `$versionofdb.Column1` as follows (slightly simplified):

```
$databaseVersion = @'
Column1
2019.3.3
2020.3
4.21.0.3
4.27.7
4.33.10
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#Calls custom function to get version of the file as System.Version type
### $version = Get-AppVersion $Source ### can't reproduce
$version = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion 

# Checks to make sure the the version in the DB is lower than that of the App version.
foreach($versionofdb in $databaseVersion) {
    if ($version -lt [version]$versionofdb.Column1) { 
        ###                               ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
        Write-Output "Database Version $($versionofdb.Column1) >= $version"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Versions $($versionofdb.Column1) < $version`: compatible"
    }
}
```

> ```
> Database Version 2019.3.3 >= 5.1.19041.1
> Database Version 2020.3 >= 5.1.19041.1
> Versions 4.21.0.3 < 5.1.19041.1: compatible
> Versions 4.27.7 < 5.1.19041.1: compatible
> Versions 4.33.10 < 5.1.19041.1: compatible
> ```

Comment: Excellent, that works fairly well. Only issue I think I'd run into is if any of the $versionofdb in $databaseVersion passes, the script would continue the way its written. I'd need the script to fail if any of those in $databaseVersion fails.

Comment: Use `exit` keyword (described in `Get-Help 'about_Language_Keywords'`) conditionally…

Comment: I think it's worth noting that PowerShell will use the `type` of the left side argument in the operation and automatically try to convert the value of the right side to match. So as long as `$version` is a `[version]` type, it will try to convert `$versionofdb.Column1` to also be a `[version]` without specifically typecasting it that way.